# How to generate a bounding box that overlaps with existing bounding box by at least a given ratio?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

Given a bounding box `bbox1`, I want to randomly generate a new bounding box `bbox2`, which overlaps `bbox1` by at least 0.5.

The overlap ratio is defined as the area of intersection between `bbox1` and `bbox2`, divided by the area of the union of the two.

The naive way I can think of is to randomly generate bounding boxes until I find one that satisfies the condition. But obviously, it will waste some time in generating and evaluating unsatisfied candidates.

If the bounding box is encoded by the upper left corner and the width and height `bbox1 = (x1, y1, w1, h1)`, the pseudocode below shows how I generate the new bounding box.

```
do
    x2 = random(x1 - w1, x1 + w1/2)
    y2 = random(y1 - h1, y1 + h1/2)
    w2 = random(0, 2 * w1)
    h2 = random(0, 2 * w1 * h1 / w2)
    bbox2 = (x2, y2, w2, h2)
while bboxOverlapRatio(bbox1, bbox2) < 0.5
```

Any better solutions? For example, can I further narrow down the random range?

Comment: There is infinitely many such bounding boxes, so what probability distribution do you have in mind? uniform is obviously not an option

Comment: Why uniform is not an option? Yes, there are infinite such bounding boxes, but the range can be narrowed down.

Comment: Oh ok I misunderstood the problem. Nevermind

Comment: Do the two bounding boxes have the same size and shape? If not, could you post the naive code that generates boxes until one fits?

Comment: @MOehm It could have different size and shape. I have posted the way I limit the range of the new bounding box.

Comment: Couldn't you set a higher lower bound for `h2` given that you have `w2`? Instead of zero, something based on original area x 0.5 / w2.

Comment: You can generate a random box and then randomly increase it until it satisfies. It's hard to estimate the resulting distribution however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to further narrow down the random range is to only generate new bounding boxes `bbox2` with the center inside `bbox1`.

If the center of `bbox2` is outside of `bbox1` then it is impossible to have an overlap of at least 0.5 (note that this is a separate, interesting mathematical problem in itself).

This additional constraint can be expressed as `x1 < x2 + w2/2 < x1 + w1` (with a similar relation for the vertical axis), and can be used to narrow the range for `w2` and `h2`:

```
do
    x2 = random(x1 - w1, x1 + w1/2)
    y2 = random(y1 - h1, y1 + h1/2)
    w2 = random(max(0, 2 * (x1 - x2)), min(2 * w1, 2 * (x1 + w1 - x2)))
    h2 = random(max(0, 2 * (y1 - y2)), min(2 * w1 * h1 / w2, 2 * (y1 + h1 - y2)))
    bbox2 = (x2, y2, w2, h2)
while bboxOverlapRatio(bbox1, bbox2) < 0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets take the case of equal size boxes:

There are four cases:

```
one where you start from the left at x1-w1/2, y1
one from the top x1, y1-h1/2
on from upper left to move in diagonal x1-c, y1-c
one from the lower left same diagonal up x1-c, y1+h1+c
```

where c is a number you can find that gives at least 1/2 overlap in the diagonal position (for a square (w-c)*(w-c)>=w^2/2 you solve this quadratic equation and find c).

The search space is limited within these areas:

so you do:

```
choice=random from 1 to 4
if choice==1: xnew=x1-w1/2+random from 0 to 2*w1; ynew=y1
if choice==2: xnew=x1; ynew=y1-h1/2+random from 0 to 2*h1
if choice==3: xnew=x1-c+random from 0 to w1+2*c; ynew=y1-c+random from 0 to h1+2*c
if choice==4: xnew=x1-c+random from 0 to w1+2*c; ynew=y1+h1+c+random from 0 to -(h1+2*c)
```

Its not a completely random selection since you dont have the seach space up front and then choose some point in it but effectively it covers the whole space randomly.

This cover the four main routes; but leaves the corner cases/spaces uncovered. You effectively have a circle search space: if you move your starting point up you have to move it right also to guarantee 1/2 overlap. That is a circle of radius w1 (if w1=h1) centered on the center of the initial rectangle. If you  start on any point on the circle you are guaranteed to have 1/2 coverage. You can pick your point anywhere within the circle.

If the rectangles are not squares but general rectangles you have an ellipse as the search space.

--

Then lets go the the different size scenario:

within your loop you pick the size at random and perform the above search.
The calculations where you start from and how far you will go change but can be done.

[Correction: the starting points cannot be on the entire circle but certain part of the circle on the left side -  symmetrical on the right side]